# $ G/H \cong K $ and $ G/K \cong H\implies G \cong H \times K $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $ (G, *) $ be a group.

Say, $ H, K \lhd G $ such that $ G/H \cong K $ and $ G/K \cong H $

Example:$\ G = Z_{4}, \ H = \{ 0, 2\}, \ K = \{ 0, 2\}  \ $ satisfies the above condition, but $ G \not\cong \{(0,0),(0,2),(2,0)(2,2) \} = H \times K$,

Here we observe that $H \cap K \not= \{(0,0)\}$

Example: $ \ G = GL(n,R), H = SL(n,R), K = Z(G)$ also satisfies the above condition, and $G = H \times K$,

Here we observe that $H \cap K = \{I_{n \times n}\}$

So, intutively I can feel that
$ \ \ G \cong H \times K \iff H \cap K = \{ e \} $

Can anyone prove or counter it?

(In case the statement is wrong, please provide an *iff* condition for $ G \cong H \times K$ where $ H, K \lhd G $ such that $ G/H \cong K $ and $ G/K \cong H $)

Comment: There is the product thm: If the intersection holds only {e} , and HK=G as sets product, with H,K normal in G, $G=H \times K$

Comment: Your 2nd example is not ok for $n$ even because $-I$ is in the intersection of the two subgroups. Other than that the statement is true provided you add to the hypotheses that the intersection is trivial.

Comment: The trick is to observe that for $x$ in $H$ and $y$ in $K$, one has that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in H\cap K$, so $x$ commutes with $y$.

Comment: I initially interpreted $G/H\simeq K$ to mean that the natural map $K\to G/H$ is an isomorphism but I see people interpreting this for its face value.  It might be good to realise that these two interpretations possibly lead to different answers so the OP would do well to clarify.

Comment: @Ruy, with [your](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983698/g-h-cong-k-and-g-k-cong-h-implies-g-cong-h-times-k#comment8220686_3983698) interpretation, we'd have:  $K \to G/H$ surjective implies that $G = K H$, and injective implies that $H \cap K = 1$, hence by normality that $G$ is the internal direct product $K \times H$, right?

Comment: @LSpice, yep, that is precisely what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have a counterexample. Let $D = \langle a,b \mid b^2=(ab)^2 = 1 \rangle$ be the infinite dihedral group, and let $X = \langle a_1,b_1 \rangle \times \langle a_1,b_2 \rangle$ be the direct product of two copies of $D$.

Now let $G = \langle a_1^2,b_1,a_2^2,b_2,a_1a_2 \rangle \le X$, and note that $|X:G| = 2$.

Let $H = \langle a_1^2,b_1 \rangle$ and $K = \langle a_2^2,b_2 \rangle$. Then $H \cong K \cong D$, and $H \times K \le G$ with $|G:(H \times K)| = 2$.

Now $G/H$ is generated by the images in $H$ of $a_1a_2$, $a_2^2$ and $b_2$, but $(a_1a_2)^2H = a_2^2H$ and $(a_1a_2b_2)^2H = H$, so $G/H \cong D \cong K$ and similarly $G/K \cong H$.

Now, since $[b_1,a_1a_2] = [b_1,a_1] = a_1^2$ and $[b_2,a_1a_2] = a_2^2$, we see that $G/[G,G]$ is a $3$-generator group (of order 8) generated by the images of $b_2$, $b_2$ and $a_1a_2$.

But  the  abelanization of $H \times K$ is a $4$-generator group of order $16$, so $G \not\cong H \times K$.

Answer (score 1):

In case $G$ is finite it is true when $H \cap K=1$: from $G/H \cong K$ it follows that $|G|=|H||K|=|HK||H \cap K|$, whence $G=HK$. From this it follows that $G \cong H \times K$.

Comment: But there is no assumption in the question that $G$ is finite, and one of the OP's examples is infinite.

Comment: Hi Derek, yes sure, I know, and that is why I said: *In case $G$ is finite*.

Comment: I am still thinking about the general case!

Comment: #metoo Wonder if there has been already an example here on MathStackexchange

Comment: As @Ruy points out in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983698/g-h-cong-k-and-g-k-cong-h-implies-g-cong-h-times-k#comment8220686_3983698), this is interpreting $G/H \cong K$ as saying that the natural map $K \to G/H$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure you're assuming [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8220761), because otherwise $H$ and $K$ could be a common cyclic subgroup of order $2$ inside the Klein $4$-group $G$, in which case we have $G/H \cong K$ but not $\lvert G\rvert = \lvert H K\rvert$.  But then you don't need order at all:  $K \to G/H$ surjective implies directly that $G = K H$; and the natural map $K \to K/H \cap K$ being an isomorphism implies that $H \cap K = 1$.  What did I misunderstand?  (Also posted [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8220793).)

Comment: @LSpice: thank you for your remark, I was too quick and imprecise. I corrected it.